# Count particular characters within a column using Spark Dataframe API

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, count

I have a column with bits in a Spark dataframe `df`. The columns are of string format:

```
10001010000000100000000000000000
10001010000000100000000100000000
```

Is there a simple and effective way to create a new column `"no_of_ones"` counting the frequency of ones using a Dataframe? Using RDDs, I can `map(lambda x:x.count('1'))` (PySpark).
Additionally, how can I retrieve a list with the position of the ones?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way I can think of is to remove all zeroes and then count the length of the field.

```python
df.show
+--------------------+
|          bytestring|
+--------------------+
|10001010000000100...|
|10001010000000100...|
+--------------------+


df.withColumn("no_of_ones" , length(regexp_replace($"bytestring", "0", "")) ).show
+--------------------+----------+
|          bytestring|no_of_ones|
+--------------------+----------+
|10001010000000100...|         4|
|10001010000000100...|         5|
+--------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, when you cannot find what you need in the predefined function of (py)spark SQL, you can write a user defined function (UDF) that does whatever you want (see [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#udf-registration-moved-to-sqlcontextudf-java--scala)).

Note that in your case, a well coded udf would probably be faster than the regex solution in scala or java because you would not need to instantiate a new string and compile a regex (a for loop would do). However it would probably be much slower in pyspark because executing python code on an executor always severely damages the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is binary(0/1) the above answer will work. Appreciate Oli's Answer.

but just in case you need to find number of occurrence of a character/number/symbols in a string which has .

Eg:

```
Find '~' in a string "ABCDE~FGH~IJAK~123~$$$"
```

Go for the following solution.

```
df.withColumn("no_of_ones" , length($"bytestring") - length(regexp_replace($"bytestring", "~", "")) ).show
```

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.4+** has [`regexp_count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_count) for the count of occurrences.

```py
F.expr(r"regexp_count(col_name, '1')")
```

<sup>Note: special characters need to be escaped using `\\`, e.g. `F.expr(r"regexp_count(col_name, '\\+')")`</sup>

Full example for *the count*:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("10001010000000100000000000000000",),
     ("10001010000000100000000100000000",)],
    ["bytestring"])

df.withColumn('no_of_ones', F.expr(r"regexp_count(bytestring, '1')")).show()
# +--------------------+----------+
# |          bytestring|no_of_ones|
# +--------------------+----------+
# |10001010000000100...|         4|
# |10001010000000100...|         5|
# +--------------------+----------+
```

---

For *the positions*, I could suggest a bit more elaborate way, involving higher-order functions [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) and [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html#pyspark.sql.functions.filter).

```py
seq = "sequence(1, length(bytestring))"
located = F.expr(f"transform({seq}, x -> locate('1', bytestring, x))")
cleaned = F.filter(F.array_distinct(located), lambda x: x != 0)

df.withColumn('pos_of_ones', cleaned).show(truncate=0)
# +--------------------------------+-----------------+
# |bytestring                      |pos_of_ones      |
# +--------------------------------+-----------------+
# |10001010000000100000000000000000|[1, 5, 7, 15]    |
# |10001010000000100000000100000000|[1, 5, 7, 15, 24]|
# +--------------------------------+-----------------+
```